# Submit a form via Ajax in Yii. Yii is double submitting the form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, yii2

I have the following:

**My View**

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'emailForm', 'action' => 'send-email', 'method' => 'post', 'enableAjaxValidation' => false, 'options' => ['class' => '']]) ?> 
<?= $form->field($emailModel, 'verifyCode')->widget(Captcha::className(), [
    'template' => '<div class="row"><div class="col-lg-3">{image}</div><div class="col-lg-6">{input}</div></div>',
]) ?>
<?= Html::submitButton('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'email-button']) ?>
```

**My Controller**

```
  public function actionSendEmail() {
    Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
    $model = new EmailModel();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
      return ['info' => "Your message has been sent!"];
    } else {
      // error
      // return $model->errors;
      return ActiveForm::validate($model);
    }
```

**My model**

```
 public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['name', 'from', 'to', 'message'], 'required'],
            [['from', 'to'], 'email'],
            ['verifyCode', 'captcha'],
        ];
```

**javascript**

```
jQuery(function() {
    $('#emailForm').submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.post('send-email', $( "#emailForm" ).serialize(), function(data) {
            console.log (data);
//          $('#emailAlert').show().empty().append(data);
        });
        return false;
enter code here
```

`event.preventDefault();` and `return false;` is not stopping Yii itself from submitting the form, so it is double submitting.

`'enableAjaxValidation' => true` causes Yii to validate the form after each & every change to each field, so I set it to false.

*Console* throws:

```
XHR finished loading: POST "http://localhost:81/shopping/send-email".send @ jquery.js
  Object {info: "Your message has been sent!"}
XHR finished loading: POST "http://localhost:81/shopping/send-email".send @ jquery.js
  Object {info: "Your message has been sent!"}
```

Comment: By reading the code I don't see any reason for the double-submission. Could you provide the generated html instead of the view only ? I think there are some missing closing (curly) brackets in the javascript snippet. Can you conform that ?

Comment: yii has its own events attached to ajax form submission. Please refer this (http://stackoverflow.com/a/28164817/5658658) . Hope you have end your ActiveForm. Which is clearly not in the code you have shared.

Comment: Try changing `$('#emailForm').submit(function(event) {` to `$('body').on('submit', '#emailForm', function(event) {` for me this always seems to stop the double submission..

Comment: @Two people. Yes, the closing tags and braces are left off for a condensed question. Yes, `ActiveForm::end()` is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ck_arjun had the solution. I had to change the JavaScript to

```
$('#emailForm').on('beforeSubmit', function(event) {
```

I had to use `.on()` because JQuery doesn't have `.beforeSubmit()` http://api.jquery.com/category/events/form-events/.